# How to make JsonCPP works in MFC c++ project

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, jsoncpp

I was able to create a test WinApp using JsonCPP (https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) to parse a json file.
However, when I implemented similar in an MFC C++ project with **C/C++ -> Precompiled Headers** option set to **Use Precompiled Header(/Yu)** in VS2008, it fails with this error:

> c:\users\user1\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\jsonutility\jsonutility\jsonTest.cpp(371) : fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "stdafx.h"' to your source?

If I add '#include "stdafx.h"' to my JsonTest.cpp, I will get this error:

> JsonTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class Json::Value & __thiscall Json::Value::operator[](char const *)" (??AValue@Json@@QAEAAV01@PBD@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall JsonTest::readConfig(char const *)" (?readConfig@JsonTest@@QAEXPBD@Z)

I have tried for almost 2 days now but no success.
I had added the following in my Additional Include Directories:

C:\Users\User1\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\JsonUtility\ReadingJson\dist

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include

C:\usr\jsoncpp-master\include

Comment: That is a linker error. If you've built jsoncpp you should have a .lib file. Add the .lib file to your project's Configuration Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I seems like you didn't include the JSONCPPs *.cpp file into your project (they have to be compiled and linked). If the library gets compiled to a static library, you have to tell the linker what to link.

Comment: I configured my project as "Use MFC in a Static Library".  I dropped dist folder in my project which includes json.h, json-forwards.h, and jsoncpp.cpp but it seemed not enough.  So I follow your suggestion by adding json_vc71_libmtd.lib to my project and adding that .lib name to the Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies and and removing the 3 json files, it fixed the issue.